# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS will not go past grub2 menu

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, hp

I have a HP Pro 3130 MT and just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. When I restart, instead of getting a ubuntu logo or going to the login page, the OS takes me to the grub2 screen that has the "Advanced options" but the astrick(*) is next to Ubuntu. I don't understand why I am not getting a normal boot to the login screen.

I figured I might be having graphics problems so I try to boot into recovery mode using the Advanced options but after I select recovery mode and hit enter, I never make it past the loading linux kernal text. I just get a frozen cursor underneath the text.

Here's the `lspci` information about my graphics chipset:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 2a9c
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
    Memory at fb800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at cc00 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

So I changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line in `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` but that didn't work. So I changed it one more time to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modest=1"`, but I am still unable to boot correctly.

I am really confused because the live disk works just fine.

Comment: Has anyone out there experienced what I am going through? I am completely stuck and don't know what I can do next to get running. If anyone can help, please leave some comments.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 in a dual-boot system. My other OS is Win XP, which I haven't used so it has nothing to do with it. Anyways, my boot did the same, I restarted and enter advanced option in GRUB and then selected the previous kernel and could work. I am working as we speak with kernel 3.11.0-20-generic (uname -a) which is previous to 3.13.0-24-generic. Still trying to fix the autoboot. Hope you could at least enter your system.